# jQuery .keyup() triggering infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get immediate feedback from an input box as to the letter that has been typed into it. The input has a maxlength of 1 character and I want jQuery to be alerted to this value the moment the user lifts their key having entered their character.

The following detects the value immediately but then keeps looping forever. This isn't strictly a problem but it seems like an undue strain.

```
$("#captcha").keyup(function(e) {
    ( $(this).val() == 'w' ) ? $(this).css("border-bottom","2px dotted #27bbb1") : $(this).css("border-bottom","2px dotted #ED0664") ;
    //e.preventDefault();
});
```

`change()` won't work as an event as this is only triggered when the user changes focus, I need this immediately after keypress.

Thanks

Comment: remove the alert or replace it with console.log

Comment: Its working fine check it over here http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/U7LML/

Comment: Which browser are you using? Seems to work fine in mine.

Comment: Yea I realise it does work, it just strikes me if something is infinitely triggering alerts then it means it's infinitely checking for something which isn't necessary in this case, I just need it checked once.

Comment: In safari it will keep alerting because of the alert, remove it ..

Comment: I dont understand the question, you only need to execute the function once?

Comment: I've removed the alerts as that's confusing things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using the enter key to dismiss the alert, which also triggers the keyup event. Try this:

```
$("#captcha").keyup(function() {
    $(this).blur();
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert( val );
});
```

Comment: I will when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine for me. Try this js fiddle I created using your script.
With following modification

```
 <form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Hello there" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>​

$("#target").keyup(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    alert( val );
});
​
```

[Yourscript working](http://jsfiddle.net/92Z5q/)